# How configure Xorg to disable DPMS completly on linux w/ SATO desktop

Tags: pi-3, xorg, yocto

Using the Raspberry Pi 3

## My Linux

It's a Yocto image with Sato desktop

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-4.1-noarch:core-4.1-arm
Distributor ID: poky
Description:    Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 1.8.1
Release:    1.8.1
Codename:   fido

root@raspberrypi3:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi3 4.1.18 #1 SMP Thu Mar 17 10:26:07 CET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

## What I have done so far

### Created 10-monitors.conf file

```
root@raspberrypi3:/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          1024 Mar 19 04:59 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          1024 Oct 19 15:15 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1099 Mar 17 08:31 10-evdev.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           330 Mar 19 04:59 10-monitors.conf
```

and added these

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    Option "DPMS" "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "ServerLayout0"
    Option "StandbyTime" "0"
    Option "SuspendTime" "0"
    Option "OffTime"     "0"
    Option "BlankTime"   "0"
EndSection
```

Inspired by this [archlinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling)

Will this work? How do I check that these were taken into effect?

## Update

```
xset -q
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

Comment: It says right on the page you linked (`xset -q`) which implies you are having a problem, e.g., *even though DPMS is disabled*, you are still getting screen blanking.  This would imply the cause is something else.  If that's the case *ask about your actual problem*: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378  If there is no problem, you already have the answer.

Comment: right, I had tried `xset`, although `xset -q` gives me an error. See update

Comment: As a matter of fact, so far it looks like my solution worked. I am attempted to leave the post though. Might be useful to others... besides having fallen in a **XY problem**

Comment: Exactly.  The next question: "Lemme guess, you called `xset` from ssh, or otherwise outside X."  It needs a display to refer to, by default the one you are using.  If you aren't in a GUI, or there isn't one running period, you'll get `unable to open display`.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need an output from `xset -q`. If you setup the Pie from ssh, add `DISPLAY=:0` to every command that gives you `unable to open display` message:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xset -q
```

Then run

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
xset s noexpose
xset s 0 0
```

or from ssh

```
DISPLAY=:0 xset -dpms
DISPLAY=:0 xset s off
DISPLAY=:0 xset s noblank
DISPLAY=:0 xset s noexpose
DISPLAY=:0 xset s 0 0
```

Keep your eye on **Screen Saver** and **DPMS** sections of `xset -q` output after each command. This way define what helps you to keep screen on.

Then add these commands to `~/.xinitrc` where they will be executed every time the Xorg server starts.